# Unexpected "space" with border

Tags: html, border

When I add a `1px border` to a div, an unexpected space appears between the border and the content inside the `div`.

With the border: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcwfc.png)

```
<div class="reporting square" style="border: 0.5px solid red; padding: 0px;">
   <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

Without the border: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS6Kd.png)

```
<div class="reporting square" style="padding: 0px;">
   <p>Hi</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used to **[Css Reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)**

or used **to** `p` `margin:0;`

```css
p{margin:0;}
```

```html
<div class="reporting square" style="border: 0.5px solid red; padding: 0px;">
<p>Hi</p>
</div>
```